# Swift Views not being recreated

Tags: swift, swiftui

In my content View, I am initializing the views "ringView" and "ringNumberView" which are shown on screen. However, the data shown by these views is constantly changing and I would like the user to be able to refresh them at any point via the "refresh" button. With the button I am attempting to reset the views with current data by recreating them but they do not changed when "refresh" is clicked.

content View:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var WeekElevation : FlightsClimbed = FlightsClimbed() //ignore this
    @State var ringView : RingView =  RingView() //creating them here
    @State var ringNumberView = RingNumbersView()
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button("refresh") { //trying to recreate them here
            ringView = RingView()
            ringNumberView = RingNumbersView()
        }
        
        ringView.frame(width: 45, height: 45)
        ringNumberView
        
        VStack { // ignore this
            Text("\(Int(WeekElevation.getFlights())) ") + Text(Image(systemName: "figure.stairs")) + Text(" in past week")
            Text("\(WeekElevation.calculatePercentEverest())% of Mt. Everest")
        }
    }
}
```

RingView:

```
import Foundation
import HealthKit
import SwiftUI

struct RingView : WKInterfaceObjectRepresentable {
    
    @StateObject var fitness = main()
    
    func makeWKInterfaceObject(context: Context) -> some WKInterfaceObject {
        
        let ringObject = WKInterfaceActivityRing()
        
        fitness.makeQuery() { summary in
            ringObject.setActivitySummary(summary, animated: true)
        }
        
        
        return ringObject
        
        
        
    }
    
    func updateWKInterfaceObject(_ wkInterfaceObject: WKInterfaceObjectType, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
}
```

RingNumbersView:

```
struct RingNumbersView: View {
    
    
    
    @StateObject var fitness = main()
    @State var ActivitySummary : HKActivitySummary = HKActivitySummary()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        let red = Int(ActivitySummary.activeEnergyBurned.doubleValue(for: .largeCalorie()))
        let green = Int(ActivitySummary.appleExerciseTime.doubleValue(for: .minute()))
        let blue = Int(ActivitySummary.appleStandHours.doubleValue(for: .count()))
        
        HStack {
            Text("\(red)").foregroundColor(.red)
            Text("\(green)").foregroundColor(.green)
            Text("\(blue)").foregroundColor(.blue)
        }.padding().onAppear(){
            fitness.authorizeHealthkit()
            fitness.makeQuery() { summary in
                ActivitySummary = summary
            }
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

Thanks very much for any help

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call

```
 main()
```

You create a different instance. One does not know about the other.

Use

```
@ObservedObject
```

Or

```
@EnvironmentObject
```

For the child Views.

Also, Views should not be in an

```
@State
```

Only in a

```
body
```

Or

```
@ViewBuilder
```